# Why doesn't my code raise "Headers already sent" warning?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.3

I always thought PHP doesn't allow sending headers after any output. I was surprised to see this doesn't cause any error in my code:

```php
<?php

echo 'z';
header('X-Foo: Bar');
echo 'y';
```

What it does is outputting `zy` and `X-Foo: Bar` header just fine. How is it possible? I'm not using output buffering.

Can output buffering be enabled by the server by default? Or maybe PHP changed the way it buffers the output by default? I'm using PHP 7.3.4. And yes, all my errors, warning and notices are set to be displayed.

I'm using the Homestead server, maybe that serves as some hint.

Comment: @DerekPollard Read the question again. OP knows that. OP's wondering why it's (apparently) **working** when it shouldn't.

Comment: it sends an error on my version 7.3.3

Comment: I've experienced this phenomenon in certain dev environments, but never did dig into why it didn't throw the notice.... I'm curious what you find.  (Note, this has been true for me in the past on PHP 5.6, haven't run into it yet in 7.2)

Comment: It should retrun `Warning` on your version too. See https://3v4l.org/EGrXp

Comment: I'd be looking at https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php. It's possible to turn on output buffering at a `php.ini` level. OP mentions Homestead - is this code within Laravel?

Comment: @ceejayoz No, it is a pure, raw script. But I'm using Laravel's server - Homestead. Maybe it does something behinds the scenes.

Comment: `echo ini_get('output_buffering');` outputs `4096`. Does it mean that Homestead turns it on by default?

Comment: @RoboRobok I can't speak for Homestead (I use Valet primarily), but that looks like it's your answer. It's not immediately clear to me from the Github laravel/homestead repo if it sets PHP defaults.

Comment: Works fine for me too, but adding flush(); after echo 'z'; I get the "Header already sent" error. So, for some reason (maybe server configuration), echo does not send directly to output.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP are you using Homestead like me?

Comment: @RoboRobok No, I'm using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in your php configuration the directive [output_buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) is enabled.

That value can be `Off` or `0` (BTW it disabled by default), or can be `On` or any integer value greater than 0, which means limitation for buffering (in bytes).